# Using ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification in background with Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am writing an app targeting iOS7 in Xamarin.iOS that is supposed to upload users' pictures to an online storage service as soon as he/she takes them. In order to do this, I set up an ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification observer, like this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver (ALAssetsLibrary.ChangedNotification, Callback);
```

and then defined a callback like this:

```
void Callback (NSNotification notification)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Received a notification ALAssetsLibrary : {0}", notification);
            //Launch picture upload here
        }
```

This works well, but only with the app open. Is there a way to make my app receive the notification (and process the upload) when it is backgrounded? I use iOS7 backgrounding for file transfers and long running tasks in other points of my app, but I wouldn't know how to apply this to the observer.
Extra question, I would also like to be able to filter out notifications received by this function so that I can launch my upload only if the operation is "new picture created" (currently I get notifications also when pictures are removed/edited/moved).
Thanks in advance for your replies :)

Comment: Apps are paused in the background, so no, you cannot use `NSNotificationCenter` in the background.

Comment: Then how do you catch pictures being taken while in the background? I know it is possible somehow, other apps (like Dropbox) do it!

Comment: Who said Dropbox does it? It does not. Which feature are you talking about?

Comment: It does, if you set the upload in background option (https://www.dropbox.com/help/500/en). From what I understand, it uses the gps background authorization to be able to run pictures upload in background.